# Initialize a Java Array in one line

Tags: java, c++, syntax

I am doing a conversion from C++ to Java.
Does anyone know how to convert it to Java?

```
typedef struct {
       int id;                
       char *old_end;        
       char *new_end;         
       int old_offset;       
       int new_offset;       
       int min_root_size;     
   int func;           
       } RuleList;

static RuleList step1a_rules[] =
       {
         101,  "sses",      "ss",    3,  1, -1,  _NULL,
         102,  "ies",       "i",     2,  0, -1,  _NULL,
         103,  "ss",        "ss",    1,  1, -1,  _NULL,
         104,  "s",         _LAMBDA,  0, -1, -1,  _NULL,
         000,  NULL,        NULL,    0,  0,  0,  _NULL,
       };
```

Thank

Comment: *"in one line"*  That is a pretty arbitrary constraint when source code's main purpose is to be human readable.  BTW - please don't forget to add a question mark to questions, and it would pay to show some (or any) effort at solving the question yourself.

Comment: If the array is of type `RuleList`, whatever that is, you have to initialize it with `RuleList` objects. You cant just place literals in the definition. You will also need to create a Java class to reflect your struct.

Comment: You're missing a bunch of braces here; around every line to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a constructor for `RuleList`:

```
class RuleList {
    int id;                
    String old_end;        
    String new_end;         
    int old_offset;       
    int new_offset;       
    int min_root_size;     
    int func;

    RuleList(int id, String old_end, String new_end, int old_offset,
        int new_offset, int min_root_size, int func)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.old_end = old_end;
        // etc.
    }
};

static RuleList[] step1a_rules = {
    new RuleList(101,  "sses",      "ss",    3,  1, -1,  _NULL),
    new RuleList(102,  "ies",       "i",     2,  0, -1,  _NULL),
    new RuleList(103,  "ss",        "ss",    1,  1, -1,  _NULL),
    new RuleList(104,  "s",         _LAMBDA, 0, -1, -1,  _NULL),
    new RuleList(000,  null,        null,    0,  0,  0,  _NULL),
};
```

This assumes that `_NULL` is a defined static `int` value and `_LAMBDA` is a defined static `String` value.

Comment: I wouldn't use underscores in variable names in Java.
Also, the line below won't compile because you're missing "new RuleList[]":
   static RuleList[] step1a_rules = {

Comment: I actually think that in recent Java versions you can omit the `new RuleList[]` before the `{`...?  Or perhaps that only works for e.g. ints.

Comment: @Ben - I was just reusing OP's variable names. I agree that they aren't the usual Java style (although they are legal in the language). The last statement is perfectly legal: it's an array initializer that doesn't need `new RuleList[]`. (See the [Java Language Specification, section 10.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.6)).

Comment: @LouisWasserman - It's not only recent versions of Java that allow you to omit the `new RuleList[]`; that goes back to the earliest days of Java. This only applies when initializing an array variable in the same statement that declares it. Elsewhere, the `new RuleList[]` is still required.

Comment: Ah, right you are.  I've actually never seen that before.  Nice to learn =)

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this in Java is below.  The RuleList class in Java is a bit more verbose than the RuleList C struct, but there are easy ways of dealing with that such as using Eclipse to generate most of the code.

```
public class RuleList {
  private final int id;                
  private final String oldEnd;        
  private final String newEnd;         
  private final int oldOffset;       
  private final int newOffset;       
  private final int minRootDize;     
  private final int func;

  public RuleList(int id, String oldEnd, String newEnd, int oldOffset,
      int newOffset, int minRootDize, int func) {
    this.id = id;
    this.oldEnd = oldEnd;
    this.newEnd = newEnd;
    this.oldOffset = oldOffset;
    this.newOffset = newOffset;
    this.minRootDize = minRootDize;
    this.func = func;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public String getOldEnd() {
    return oldEnd;
  }
  public String getNewEnd() {
    return newEnd;
  }
  public int getOldOffset() {
    return oldOffset;
  }
  public int getNewOffset() {
    return newOffset;
  }
  public int getMinRootDize() {
    return minRootDize;
  }
  public int getFunc() {
    return func;
  }
}

RuleList[] step1aRules = new RuleList[] {
   new RuleList(101,  "sses",      "ss",    3,  1, -1,  0),
   new RuleList(102,  "ies",       "i",     2,  0, -1,  0),
   new RuleList(103,  "ss",        "ss",    1,  1, -1,  0),
   new RuleList(104,  "s",         _LAMBDA,  0, -1, -1,  0),
   new RuleList(000,  null,        null,    0,  0,  0,  0),
 };
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you use final for variable ? it means does it relative with above C++ code ? Thanks.

Comment: It means you don't plan on changing the value of the variable after constructing your RuleList.  If you'd like to be able to change the value then you should remove the final and add a setter like: public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

Comment: The `new RuleList[]` is unnecessary in the last statement. Also, since the member variables are declared `final`, one could just as well make them public and dispense with the accessor functions.

Comment: Ah, cool.  I learned something new today.  Never knew the "new RuleList[]" was optional.

Comment: I disagree with making the member variables public.  Much better to use an accessor function so that you can add additional logic to them later if needed.

Comment: me,too. I always use `new RuleList` (maybe because first time I changed to Java, I see one person do this, and I think that must). Yes, I getter/setter is a part of OOP. but, manytimes, it makes me frustrate :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class RuleList, after that create an array of this class:

```
public class RuleList{
   int id ;           
   char old_end;  //note that java does not use (* for pointer like C++)       
   char new_end;         
   int old_offset;       
}

static RuleList[] step1a_rules = new RuleList[]{
                  new RuleList (101,"sses","ss",3, 1,-1,  0),... };
```

In above code, you will see something different from C++ because with Java, almost everything is object. so you declare step1a_rules is an array contain other objects (`Rulelist`). So, each object of this class, you must use keyword `new` to instance new object.

@ edit : Ah, and I almost forget: you should notice that, java and C++ has some different: in C++ class, default member is private. and in Java class, default member is public. Of course, your above code is no problem, because default member of struct is public too :D

Comment: In Java classes, the default access is _package private_: accessible only to code defined in the same package. Also, the `new RuleList[]` is unnecessary in the last statement. Also, did you try this? You need to explicitly declare `RuleList` constructors that accepts arguments.